# Erro ao gerar um exe em python com o pandas-gbq

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

Estou tentando converter um fonte para exe. Digito o comando:

```
pyinstaller --onefile arquivo.spec
```

Mostra que foi realizado com sucesso, mas quando clico no exe, aparece a mensagem

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pandas-gbq'. 
  pandas-gbq is required to load data from Google BigQuery. 
  See the docs: https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io. 
  Use pip or conda to install pandas-gbq.
```

Já fiz a instalação da biblioteca. Fiz a atualização da mesma. Mesmo assim, não funciona.

Versões instaladas na máquina:

```
PyInstaller                   3.6|
setuptools                    44.0.0|
pandas                        1.1.4|
pandas-gbq                    0.14.1
```

Comment: E qual foi o comando do pyinstaller que executou?

Comment: boa tarde, foi esse "pyinstaller --onefile arquivo.spec"